# Search in non-English language returns only one result

Tags: search

When I try to search in my (Greek) website it always returns a single result despite searching for article titles I know should return multiple results.

More specifically if i search for Μουσείo (Museum) it only returns a single result, despite the fact that I have at least a dozen articles about museums whose titles are Museum of Something

Contents of `searchform.php`:

```
<aside class="widget_search">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php __('Search for:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" value="Search" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" results=5 autosave="un1qu3_aut0s@v3_v@l" value="<?php esc_attr(apply_filters('the_search_query', get_search_query())) ?>" name="s" id="s">
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr__('Search') ?>" />
    </form>
</aside>
```

Contents of `search.php` (can also be found on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/FMwacfPG)):

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Search Results pages.
 *
 * @package Toolbox
 * @since Toolbox 0.1
 */

get_header(); ?>

        <section id="primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <header class="search-page-header">
                    <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'toolbox' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
                </header>

                <?php //toolbox_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <ul id="sfpw">
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <li><div class="sfpw-li-wrapper">
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>
                    </div></li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php toolbox_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

            <?php else : ?>

                <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'toolbox' ); ?></h1>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search terms. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'toolbox' ); ?></p>
                        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                </article><!-- #post-0 -->

            <?php endif; ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What is going wrong? I can search through the posts fine through the backend

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to TwentyEleven. Does it still happen?

Comment: The template is irrelevant. Try querying the DB yourself and see if you get more results. `SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%Μουσείo%'`. If you don't, then at least you know the problem is in your db (bad encoding?)

Comment: it cant be bad encoding, I can search the posts perfectly through the backend

Comment: *shouldnt be encoding

Comment: Does your search work as expected when using only English language?

Comment: is your wp installation in greek?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to put the following code

```
global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query->request);
```

before the

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
```

line to check the exact SQL statement. Maybe running it did return only one result.